# Python-chess : How to make infinite analysis in multiPV mode?

Tags: engines, analysis

I need to run infinite analysis in multiPV mode.
How to do it right? My code doesn't work.

```
original_fen = "7k/1b1r1pp1/3Bp1np/1p2P1q1/8/1PQB2P1/2R2P1P/6K1 b - - 3 23" 
original_board = chess.Board(original_fen)
full_path = PATH + ENGINE_NAME_FIRST
engine = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci(full_path)
with engine.analysis(original_board, multipv=MULTI_PV) as analysis:
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to open a UCI connection, and then issue the following command:

```
go infinite
```

And then issue 'stop' to the engine when you would like to stop the search.

The documentation is simple and has everything.